# Release textures (GLKTextureInfo objects) allocated by GLKTextureLoader

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

New to developing on iOS and in particular the new OpenGL related features on iOS 5, so I apologize if any of my questions are so basic.

The app I am working on is designed to receive camera frames and display them on screen via OpenGL ES (the graphic folks will take over this and add the actual OpenGL drawing about which I know very little). The application is developed XCode4, and the target is iPhone4 running iOS 5. For the moment, I used the ARC and the GLKit functionality and all is working fine except for the memory leak in loading the images as texture. The app receives a "memory warning" very soon.

Specifically, I would like to ask how to release the textures allocated by

```
@property(retain) GLKTextureInfo *texture;

-(void)setTextureCGImage:(CGImageRef)image 
{
    NSError *error;

    self.texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image options:nil error:&error];

    if (error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error loading texture from image: %@",error);
    }
}
```

The `image` is a quartz image built from the camera frame (sample code from apple). I know the problem is not in that part of the code since if I disable the assignment, the app does not receive the warning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Super hacky solution I believe, but it seems to work:

Add the following before the assignment:

```
GLuint name = self.texture.name;
glDeleteTextures(1, &name);
```

If there's a more official way (or if this is the official way), I would appreciate if someone could let me know.

Comment: Hmmm. No responses so far, so this is as official as it gets for me at the moment. :-) My thinking would be that the `GLKTextureInfo` would manage this (i.e. handle releasing the textures it points to when it is deallocated) but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: I believe this is the correct way to do it. The issue is that after your textureInfo is created when you bind the texture to GL, GL then owns the memory, therefore you need to use GL to delete the memory

Comment: Anthoys' explanation makes sense to me. +1.

Comment: _+1_: It worked for me.  And it seems to be fairly safe; if texture is `nil`, texture.name will be `nil`/`0` and glDeleteTextures ignores `0`.

Comment: So bright idea! I could kiss you on the texture to thank you!

Comment: Not hacky. From the `GLKTextureLoader` class reference: "The `GLKTextureLoader` and `GLKTextureInfo` classes do not manage the OpenGL texture for you. Once the texture is returned to your app, you are responsible for it. This means that after your app is finished using an OpenGL texture, it must explicitly deallocate it by calling the `glDeleteTextures` function."

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer, but something I noticed and it wont really fit in a comment.

If you're using `GLKTextureLoader` to load textures in the background to replace an existing texture, you have to delete the existing texture on the main thread. Deleting a texture in the completion handler *will not work.*

AFAIK this is because:

1. Every iOS thread requires its own EAGLContext, so the background queue has its own thread with its own context.
2. The completion handler is run on the queue you passed in, which is most likely not the main queue. (Else you wouldn't be doing the loading in the background...)

That is, **this will leak memory**.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft:@YES};
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
[self.asyncTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:@"my_texture_path.png"
                                           options:options
                                             queue:queue
                                 completionHandler:^(GLKTextureInfo *texture, NSError *e){
                                    GLuint name = self.myTexture.name;
                                    //
                                    // This delete textures call has no effect!!!
                                    //
                                    glDeleteTextures(1, &name);
                                    self.myTexture = texture;
                                  }];
```

To get around this issue you can either:

1. Delete the texture before the upload happens. Potentially sketchy depending on how your GL is architected.
2. Delete the texture on the main queue in the completion handler.

So, to fix the leak you need to do this:

```
//
// Method #1, delete before upload happens.
// Executed on the main thread so it works as expected.
// Potentially leaves some GL content untextured if you're still drawing it
// while the texture is being loaded in.
//

// Done on the main thread so it works as expected
GLuint name = self.myTexture.name;
glDeleteTextures(1, &name)

NSDictionary *options = @{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft:@YES};
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
[self.asyncTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:@"my_texture_path.png"
                                           options:options
                                             queue:queue
                                 completionHandler:^(GLKTextureInfo *texture, NSError *e){
                                    // no delete required, done previously.
                                    self.myTexture = texture;
                                  }];
```

or

```
//
// Method #2, delete in completion handler but do it on the main thread.
//
NSDictionary *options = @{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft:@YES};
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
[self.asyncTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:@"my_texture_path.png"
                                           options:options
                                             queue:queue
                                 completionHandler:^(GLKTextureInfo *texture, NSError *e){
                                    // you could potentially do non-gl related work here, still in the background
                                    // ...

                                    // Force the actual texture delete and re-assignment to happen on the main thread.
                                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      GLuint name = self.myTexture.name;
                                      glDeleteTextures(1, &name);
                                      self.myTexture = texture;
                                    });
                                  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to simply replace the contents of the texture to the same GLKTextureInfo.name handle? When using glgentextures you can use the returned texture handle to load new texuture data using glteximage2d. But with GLKTextureLoader it seems that glgentextures is being called every time new texture data is loaded...